# variables in SQLAlchemy chaining not working in Where clause

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, python-3.4

From the book Essential SQL Alchemy edition 2 I took this example:

```
def get_orders_by_customer(cust_name):
    columns = [orders.c.order_id, users.c.username, users.c.phone,
               cookies.c.cookie_name, line_items.c.quantity,
               line_items.c.extended_cost]
    cust_orders = select(columns)
    cust_orders = cust_orders.select_from(
        users.join(orders).join(line_items).join(cookies))
    cust_orders = cust_orders.where(users.c.username == "cakeeater")
    result = connection.execute(cust_orders).fetchall()    
    return result

get_orders_by_customer("cakeeater")
```

However when I look at the raw SQL that is generated it looks like this:

```
SELECT orders.order_id, users.username, users.phone, cookies.cookie_name, line_items.quantity, line_items.extended_cost 
FROM users JOIN orders ON users.user_id = orders.user_id JOIN line_items ON orders.order_id = line_items.order_id JOIN cookies ON cookies.cookie_id = line_items.cookie_id 
WHERE users.username = :username_1
```

Now the funny thing here is that instead of `"cakeeater"` the SQL is showing `:username_1`

As a logical result the query does not return any values.

The database I am using is Postgres
Python version 3.4.3
SQLAlchemy version 1.0.12

Could someone help me get this right?

Answer (score 0):

it is sqlalchemy logging format. ":username_1" will be replaced by your variable.
Try to run

```
SELECT orders.order_id,
       users.username,
       users.phone,
       cookies.cookie_name,
       line_items.quantity,
       line_items.extended_cost
FROM users
JOIN orders ON users.user_id = orders.user_id
JOIN line_items ON orders.order_id = line_items.order_id
JOIN cookies ON cookies.cookie_id = line_items.cookie_id
WHERE users.username = 'cakeeater';
```

on your psql console, maybe you'll get an empty result.

PS: check your sql. Try to replace `join` by `outerjoin`

Comment: I have run the query from the console and it is returning the results I expected. And it was not empty